# Python array issues while printing the logs

Tags: python, arrays

Could anyone please give me a hand? 
While saving the values of an array to variables to storage them in a log. The value of the array is being save as many times as the index for instance if the index is one the value in the array is captured just once and saved in the log but if the index is two the value of the array is captured 2 times and duplicated and the same behavior is increasing depending of the value in the index.

```
      'lass tmonCon():

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.DEBUG):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(' %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler = logging.FileHandler('C:\\config\\' + log_file)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# conection to the database to get the Webtmon details
try:
    connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname='TMONNETWarehouse' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='John1710'")
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")
# Read the db and assign the details to a variable
cur = connect.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT "Type","Realtime", "LowerBoundary", "NAID", "RecordTime" FROM "Boundaries" """)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for i in range (len(rows)):
    logType = rows[i][0]
    logRealT = rows[i][1]
    logLowerB = rows[i][2]
    logNaid  = rows[i][3]
    logRecordT = rows[i][4]
    logSearch = setup_logger('tmonSearch', 'tmonSearch')
    logSearch.info(str(logType)+", " + str(logRealT) + ", " + str(logLowerB) +", "+str(logNaid)+", "+str(logRecordT))
#print (logType, logRealT, logLowerB, logNaid, logRecordT)
# logSearch = setup_logger('tmonSearch', 'tmonSearch')
#logSearch.info(rows)

# import variable from the main class and use variables for calculation
# ***************************************************************
# * Add the filter method to determine if the alert needs to be *
# * sent                                             *
# *                                                             *
# ***************************************************************
for i in range (len(rows)):
    if (rows[i][1] < rows[i][2] * tmonMain.DELTA_ADJUST) and (rows[i][1] < rows[i][2] - tmonMain.DELTA_ADJUST):
        RealT = rows[i][1]
        NETID = rows[i][3]
        RecTime = rows[i][4]
        logCount = setup_logger('tmonCount', 'tmonCount')
        logCount.warning(str(RealT)+"," + str(NETID) + "," + str(RecTime))
        reminder = 0'
```

My logs are you can see the 4th value being increased every loop
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, MXO1Z, 2018-05-30 16:59:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, RO335, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, RO335, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, PKL55, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, PKL55, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, PKL55, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, GU587, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, GU587, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, GU587, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO P, 0.0, 0.0, GU587, 2018-05-30 16:58:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, PK999, 2018-05-30 17:00:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, PK999, 2018-05-30 17:00:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, PK999, 2018-05-30 17:00:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, PK999, 2018-05-30 17:00:00
 INFO T, 0.0, 0.0, PK999, 2018-05-30 17:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup_logger adds a handler on each iteration. The result is, on iteration N, N handlers will be printing the same message.

Just move it out of the loop (I also cleaned up the loop)

```
log_search = setup_logger('tmonSearch', 'tmonSearch')

for row in rows:
    log_search.info(', '.join((str(r) for r in row)))  # not sure if str conversion is needed
```

Comment: I just printed the values and you are right. There is something wrong while saving the values in the log file. I uploaded the rest of my code, could you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, you are a master piece.